# ClickOnce publishing incomplete and then removes everything

Tags: winforms, visual-studio-2013, ftp, clickonce

I am using Visual Studio Express 2013 and trying to deploy Windows forms software to a web server, running Windows Server 2012. It is failing consistently as follows:

1. It successfully uploads 16 supporting DLL, ranging in size from 74KB
   to 5,679KB
2. It successfully uploads a DLL that is part of the solution being
   deployed
3. It adds the .application and .exe.config.deploy files both at 0KB
4. It successfully uploads .exe.deploy and .exe.manifest
5. It successfully uploads another DLL that is part of the solution
   being deployed
6. It appears to (see later error message) successfully upload a
   .ico.deploy file
7. Then all files except two (.application and 
   name>.exe.config.deploy) are removed and the 
   name>.exe.config.deploy file is shown as 1KB, rather than 0KB as
   before.
8. A refresh of the folder then shows the .application as
   11KB, rather than 0KB as before.
9. Then these files disappear as well, leaving an empty folder.

According to Visual Studio three files failed:

- .application
- .exe.config.deploy
- .ico.deploy

The same error is given for each failed file:

> Failed to copy file  to . Unable to add  to the Web site.  Can't connect to  on port 21. Check the server name and proxy settings. If the settings are correct, the server may be temporarily unavailable.

This seems very odd given that it has successfully connected to the FTP server to upload all the preceding files.

I have tried massively extending timeouts on the FTP site but it made no difference.

Any ideas?

Thanks
Gee